# Infinite loop - Jquery plugin (address)

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, infinite-loop

I'm using current jQuery plugin (address) and I have this code (I'm using "SEO" method of address plugin)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.address.crawlable(1).state('/').init(function() {
        $('body').delegate('.ajax', 'click', function() {
            $('.ajax').address();
        });
        $('.ajax').address();
    }).change(function(e) {
        var loc = document.location.href;
        if (loc != 'http://secret.riseofkings.net' + e.value) {
            var myStr = e.value;
            myStr = myStr.substr(1);
            if (myStr) {

                $("#content").html('<img src="/images/ajax.gif" />');
                $("#iframe_space").html('<iframe src="http://riseofkings.net/nothing.php" style="display:none"></iframe>');
                var url = $(e).val().toLowerCase().substr(1).replace(/ /g, '%20');
                $("#content").load(url + '&ajax=1', function() {
                    $("#iframe_space").html('');
                }, function(errr) {
                    alert('Something went wrong. Sorry for problems');
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

## UPDATE:

when I try to add

`alert(loc+' vs http://<?php echo $security->host()."'"; ?>+e.value);`

after

```
if (loc != 'http://secret.riseofkings.net' + e.value) {
```

it gives me http://secret.riseofkings.net/game.php vs  http://secret.riseofkings.net/
When I go to link (/game.php?what=map) it alerts http://secret.riseofkings.net/game.php vs  http://secret.riseofkings.net/game.php?what=map

## ENDUPDATE;

## UPDATE2:

this is happening, for example in `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; cs; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2`

## ENDUPDATE;

but in some Firefox versions (3.XX) and IE there is an infinite loop. I do visit main page, and it starts to reload and to append `#/game.php?r=something` to the end of address in address bar.

Don't you know what's wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this line:

```
clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout(timer);
```

is wrong and scary; should be just:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: question updated with new code (deleted setTimeout and clearTimeout completelly)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with JQuery Address in my asp.net MVC site. if i clicked back to a page with a hash url it would freak out and endlessly loop the page. it turned out the problem was linked to an old version of MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftAjax.debug.js files that come standard with mvc.

if you open the MicrosoftAjax.debug.js file and you see FileVersion: 4.0.20526.0 (which is the default version with the mvc template) then upgrade the debug and compressed versions from the cdn (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax4.ashx)

please note this solution was found in another question here on stack overflow, so its not my solution. im trying to find the original question and who gave the solution.

EDIT : [Firefox 6 Infinite Page Refresh With Page With Hash Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110023/firefox-6-infinite-page-refresh-with-page-with-hash-tags)