# Page reloades in Firefox when using anchor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

**Hi,**

I have a ASP.NET MVC application that runs Microsoft Ajax and jQquery. If I run the following url in firefox :

```
http://localhost:16055/Ad/Detail/13#contactMail
```

The page will reload itself again and again? If I run the same url in Explorer or Chrome nothing will happen (the correct behavior)?

When removing this script includes the reload will stop in Firefox :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

Then I will just get a error (not found) in MicrosoftMvcValidation.js.

This is true for all pages, even for the ones without editors.

Any idea?

Comment: What version of FireFox? (And the other browsers).

Comment: Firefox 6.0, Explorer 8, Google Chrome 13.0.782

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might have a version of MicrosoftAjax.js with a bug - sounds like exactly the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110023/firefox-6-infinite-page-refresh-with-page-with-hash-tags) had. You can get the latest version [here](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js).