# Jquery hashchange problems in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

I am having a problem with the hashchange event in Firefox. We are using the JQuery hashchange plugin provided by Ben Alman. The code is as follows.

```
$(window).hashchange(function (e) {
    alert("Hello");
    //we want to perform a post in here.
});
var temp = "#123";
if (temp !== "") {
    if (window.location.hash == temp) {
        $(window).hashchange();
    } 
    else{
        window.location.hash = temp;
    }
} 
else {
    window.location.hash = "#Home/Home";
};
```

Now this works fine in IE9 and Chrome, however in Firefox, I see the alert, but as soon as I click OK, the page refreshes, displays the alert again, and continues infinitely. Is there some sort of weird behaviour that Firefox uses that I am unaware of? Or is there simply some other problem that is hidden deeper?

Comment: I don't have that problem in FF 9.0.1 or 10.0.2. It shows the alert, I hit OK, and then nothing.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so that people can easily find it in the future.

Comment: Will do, just waiting for the 8 hour time frame to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We located the problem as occuring in MicrosoftAjax.js and found the following solution:
[Firefox 6 Infinite Page Refresh With Page With Hash Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110023/firefox-6-infinite-page-refresh-with-page-with-hash-tags)

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers `window.location.hash` includes the `#` and in some don't so its better if your ignore it while comparing the hash value in your code.

Try this.

```
$(window).hashchange(function (e) {
    alert("Hello");
    //we want to perform a post in here.
});
//Remove hash from here which will be compared with window.location.hash
var temp = "123";
if (temp !== "") {
    //Replace # by empty nothing
    if (window.location.hash.replace('#', '') == temp) {
        $(window).hashchange();
    } 
    else{
        window.location.hash = '#' + temp;//Now add the hash here
    }
} 
else {
    window.location.hash = "#Home/Home";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this was not the problem. We found the solution to the problem here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110023/firefox-6-infinite-page-refresh-with-page-with-hash-tags