# ExtJS: Firefox loads empty application.js when hash "#" is in url

Tags: firefox, extjs, extjs4.2, window.location

When I try to load my application (ExtJS 4.2.3) in Firefox 32 with something in location.hash it terribly fails in reloading infinite loop. 
e.g:

`http://localhost/myapp/#test` -> fails, reloads infinitely

`http://localhost/myapp` -> loads ok

This happens only in Firefox, other browsers works ok. 
The console error says:

> Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'app/application.js', please verify that the file exists

application.js file of course exists, but what I found out is that firefox loads it empty, even if server returns it ok. 
This is screenshot from firefox network inspection: 
https://mrkr.io/h5068OVyo0

When I try to resend it in firefox network tab, it returns it ok then. 
This seems really strange to me, any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi ma2s, I just tested this locally with Google Chrome and Firefox (for OSX) and both loaded just fine, I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue using ExtJS 5.0.1 and 4.2.1. Maybe you are doing something to handle your hash tags inside your project that might be breaking your app inside Firefox. (Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/daSAYCJF)

Comment: Hey Guilherme, I eventually found out that it was caused by outdated MicrosoftAjax.js file, bug described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110023/firefox-6-infinite-page-refresh-with-page-with-hash-tags/7111848#7111848 . Anyways, thank you very much for your time.